# Error "405 Method Not Allowed" Fast API PUT method

Tags: python, mongodb, api, rest, fastapi

I encounter an error 405 during a PUT request.
I have a list of ids `ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and my goal is to update two field `activated_at` and `updated_at` with the current date time.

```
query.py
--------
async def validate(ids: list) -> Array:
    """Validates a list of FDES in the database"""

    # Preparing the updates

    updates = {
        "updated_at": datetime.now(),
        "validated_at": datetime.now()
    }

    # Making the updates
    await db.fdeses.updateMany({"id": {"$in": ids}}, {"$set": updates})

    # Returning the modified document
    documents = await db.fdeses.find({"id": {"$in": ids}}).to_list(CURSOR_LIMIT)

    return documents
```

```
controllers.py
--------------

async def validate(ids:list) -> Fdeses:

    db_fdeses = await queries.fdes.validate(ids)
    return db_fdeses
```

```
router.py
---------

@router.put("/admin/fdes/activate", response_model=Fdeses)
async def validate(ids:list = Body(...))->Fdeses:

    response = await controllers.fdes.validate(ids)

    return response
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my code. What 405 error exactly mean?

EDIT:
I tried a PUT method using Postman instead of my VueJS client and I have an error 500.

Why my backend return me errors on other functions than functions I use for this endpoint? In this case it returns me errors about PUT function for `/admin/fdes` and GET function for `admin/fdes`.

Here is the error on FastAPI:

```
INFO:     172.20.0.1:65334 - "PUT /admin/fdes/activate HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error

  File "./app/routers/fdes.py", line 40, in put_fdes

    response = await controllers.fdes.update_fdes(fdes_id, fdes)

  File "./app/controllers/fdes.py", line 57, in update_fdes

    db_fdes = await queries.fdes.select_fdes(fdes_id)

  File "./app/models/queries/fdes.py", line 16, in select_fdes

    fdes_id = ObjectId(fdes_id)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 110, in __init__

    self.__validate(oid)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 213, in __validate

    _raise_invalid_id(oid)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bson/objectid.py", line 38, in _raise_invalid_id

    raise InvalidId(

bson.errors.InvalidId: 'activate' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string
```

Comment: 405 usually means that there isn't a `PUT` method defined for the endpoint you're hitting. Confirm that you're actually making a PUT request, that you're actually calling the endpoint you're calling - and try to change `put` to something other than PUT to see if you manage to trigger it then (by just using `GET` instead, for example).